# setOnClickListener inside flipviewpager not working

Tags: android

I am using [this Link](https://github.com/Yalantis/FlipViewPager.Draco)

Inside in list item on click Toast happens but I want the click should happen after flipping of list view on Textview and it should open a fragment.Please suggest me some way to implement it.

Help would be appreciated above stars.

```
    FlipSettings settings = new   FlipSettings.Builder().defaultPage(1).build();
    friends.setAdapter(new FriendsAdapter(getActivity(), Utils.friends, settings));
    friends.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Friend f = (Friend) friends.getAdapter().getItem(position);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), f.getNickname(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: On list item click Toast happens but we can flip the list item... after flipping the list item i want to click on an textview and open a new fragment....?

Comment: github.com/Yalantis/FlipViewPager.Draco/issues/5

Comment: I have done the asked problem via http://android-delight.blogspot.in/2015/04/flipviewpager-in-list-view.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32269094/how-to-flip-the-list-item-on-click-flipviewpager-android

Answer (score 0):

Kindly look out the FlipViewPager its been extended from FrameLayout class. And here the issue is framelayout is not clickable, because viewgroup forces onintercepttouchevent to return false. Since you can't make click event inside the FlipViewPager for any view.
The solution i have made here is as follow :
step 1 : Drop a button in friends_info.xml and name it as detailButton.
step 2 : Now open-up the FlipViewPager class and declare an OnClickListener as global.
step 3 : Override setOnClickListener method as shown below

```
 @Override
    public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener l) {
        super.setOnClickListener(l);
        mOnClickListener = l;
    }
```

step 4 : Here is the trick! we are catching the click event from onInterceptTouchEvent method. Go to onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) method and write a logic as below

```
if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && !flipping) return mOnClickListener != null;
```

The above statement checks that the click event has occurred and flipping event not and return true;

And in FriendsActivity declare the button Button details; inside the FriendsHolder class which is inside FriendsAdapter.
Then go to getPage method for initialize the button.
Inside if (convertView == null) statement initialize as  holder.details = (Button) holder.infoPage.findViewById(R.id.detailButton);
and add the on click listener as well

```
 holder.details.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hurray! You clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
```

That's it!