# How to flip the list item on click flipviewpager android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I am using https://github.com/Yalantis/FlipViewPager.Draco library.

In this library we can flip the list item by swiping it like a notebook page.

Now what i want to flip the list item on click on the list item(by swiping its working fine).

Please suggest me how to do it?

Comment: There is a method in BaseflipAdapter.java, public void onFlipped(int page) whenever we swipe the page it gets called.But i am not getting how to implement the swipe gets called on listview item onclick called in friendsActivity

Comment: Hi! Did you managed to do this? I want exactly the same behaviour :)